# How to make a Youtube window on android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, youtube, youtube-api

I need to make a little window just like from Youtube's related videos, but on Android. I know that ACTION_VIEW intent can start a video, but what I'm looking for is that little window.
How do I do that?

Comment: You can use Youtube android native player. https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/register    and then follow the below link http://googledevelopers.blogspot.ca/2012/12/no-webview-required-with-native-youtube.html

Comment: try this code: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android-app/